# X Axis not displaying correctly as in the dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a simple multi line plot. The X axis corresponds to a column called "TimePeriodId" and begins at 201901 (Jan 2019) and ends at 202005 (May 2020). For some reason when I try to plot the lines the x axis doesn't take these values and displays "201825", "201850" and so on. It is almost as if it is counting the quarters of the year. Additionally, I have not included the time periods for 2018 except for 201811 (November) and 201812 (December). My question is therefore how can I force the plot to use each row entry as a data point on the graph so that the plot's x axis is correct.

The Code for this plot is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
sns.set_context("paper")


pc_plt = pc.plot(x="TimePeriodId", y=["Self_Admin_Billings", "Head_Office_Billings", "TotalLives"], kind="line")
pc_plt.set_ylim([-0.15, None])
plt.xlabel("Time Period")
plt.ylabel("Percent Change")
plt.title("Percent Change of Billings and Total Lives Since Jan-2019")
plt.show()
```

There are two attached images. One is the dataframe which I am using to plot. You will notice the TimePeriodID column goes from 202005 down to 201811. The next image attached is the plot. Again notice how the X Axis is NOT being displayed correctly.

Thank you for the input :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The problem is that it is interpreting as numerical data instead.
It will plot this way unless you define the ticks with
plt.xticks().
See documentation https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Comment: I have tried looking into the x_ticks documentation but I have not been able to resolve the issue. Is there not a way that I could change the TimePeriodId to a string and have python plot it based off that?

Answer (score 2):

You can set by hand where you want ticks on X-axis to be.

https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

from provided link, c/p of the part that you might be interested in:

```
>>> locs, labels = xticks()  # Get the current locations and labels.
>>> xticks(np.arange(0, 1, step=0.2))  # Set label locations.
>>> xticks(np.arange(3), ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Sue'])  # Set text labels.
>>> xticks([0, 1, 2], ['January', 'February', 'March'],
...        rotation=20)  # Set text labels and properties.
>>> xticks([])  # Disable xticks.
```